# using the <set> tag in SVG to change the rotation of a shape

Tags: animation, svg, transform, smil

I am trying to set the rotated angle of a shape using the <set> tag but for the life of me I cant figure it out. What is the right syntax?

```xml
<set id="smallGearJump" 
         attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" 
         to="110 100 100" begin="1s" dur="1.7s" />
```

Edit: Clarification - I am trying to set it to a specific angle for a set time, not animate it there. I want it to jump from 0 rotation to 110 (in this example above)

Comment: This *should* work, but it doesn't: `<set attributeName="transform" to="rotate(110 100 100)" begin="1s" dur="1.7s"/>` I need to do the same thing but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an animation to jump from one state to another then specify calcMode="discrete". Like this for instance:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" to="110 100 100" dur="1.7s" begin="1s"
            calcMode="discrete" />
```

Comment: Took me a while but I finally got back to this. Cheers for the answer.

Comment: `attributeName="transform"` could be required

Answer (score 2):

You need the `animateTransform` element not `animate`. You may want to modify the `additive` and `fill` properties depending on your needs.

```xml
<animateTransform id="smallGearJump"
                attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                type="rotate" to="110 100 100" dur="1.7s" begin="1s"
                additive="replace" fill="freeze" />
```

See the docu at [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateTransformElement) or at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/animateTransform).

Comment: animateTransform cannot be used with a zero duration, so it is not a discrete setting, as asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a work around for your question.
    Found that the behavior of the `set` as, when you give it wrong attribute values, it triggers the onbegin event and does nothing to the element.
    So, using that, i have given wrong attribute values for the "to" attribute. So the set command triggers the begin event after `2s`, but no transformation is applied to the element.
    Then, inside the onbegin event handler, i get the target element which in this case is rect with id `c1`. Then i apply the required transformation to it.(rotate 110 about center.)

Also the onend is triggered after `5s`. Inside that, i test for the fill attribute value, and decide whether to revert the applied transformation.

This may be a work around but, there is no compromise in the begin value, duration value.

Also

`<set attributeName="transform" to="200" ... />` translates in x dir with set behaviour

`<set attributeName="transform" to="200 100" ... />` translates 200 in x dir and 100 in y dir with set behaviour

But cant find the syntax for rotate.

Placed a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AA2tT/

Comment: -1 the question didn't ask for a Javascript solution, but for the correct declarative way to suddenly change the transform property, without any animation.

Comment: Worth noting if anyone is having problems, that onend and onbegin don't get triggered in certain Chrome and Opera versions. There is a bug out on this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I finally coded it like this:

- put the original element away in a `<defs>`
- make two `<use>` of the element, one with the additional rotation, the other without
- set the two `<use>` to visible or hidden during the animation, according to the requirements

Example:

```
<defs>
  <path id="example" d="..."/>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#example" visibility="hidden">
  <set begin="0s" end="1s" attributeName="visibility" to="visible"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#example" visibility="hidden" transform="rotate(110 100 100)">
  <set begin="1s" end="3s" attributeName="visibility" to="visible"/>
</use>
```